# customize state parameter with Oauth2client using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, openid-connect

I want to customize state parameter with Oauth2client using spring security OIDC. I am using spring reactive. The issue is I am not able to add customize state in client registration. Below is my security configuration.

```
@Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/","/jwt").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2Client()
                .build();
    }

@Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository reactiveClientRegistrationRepository(RegisteredClients clients) {
        List<ClientRegistration> clientRegistrations = clients.getClients()
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(clientRegistration -> {
                    String registrationId = clientRegistration.getKey();
                    RegisteredClients.OAuthClient client = clientRegistration.getValue();

                    return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationId)
                            .clientId(client.getClientId())
                            .clientSecret(client.getClientSecret())
                            .redirectUriTemplate(client.getRedirectUri())
                            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                            .tokenUri(client.getTokenUri())
                            .authorizationUri(client.getAuthorizationUri())
                            .scope("openid")
                            .build();
                })
                .collect(toList());
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrations);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To customize the authorization request, you should wire an `ServerAuthorizationRequestResolver`:

```java
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
        // ...
        .oauth2Client((oauth2) -> oauth2
            .authorizationEndpoint((authorization) -> authorization
                .authorizationRequestResolver(authorizationRequestResolver)
            )
        )
        .build();
}

@Bean
OAuth2ServerAuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver
    (ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository registrations) {

    DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver = 
        new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(registrations);
    resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer((request) -> request.state(...));
    return resolver;
}
```

Spring Security has [some related servlet documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#customizing-the-authorization-request) that may be useful as well.